# How to extract id and url from an anchor tag in this code using PHP?

Tags: php, html, regex, tags, extract

I am trying to extract the text,url(href) and id from an anchor tag. Up to now, I could get the text between anchor tags.
This is my code

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
      <?php
    $html =<a href='https://www.google.lk/' id='21'>Google</a>  <a>Solution</a>"
    preg_match_all('@<(a)>(.+?)</\1>@is', $html, $matches);
    foreach ($matches[2] as $text) {
      print "Text: $text\n";
      echo "<br>";
    }
    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

This will give the following result.

**Text: Solution**

In this way, I can only print the text between 2 pure anchor tags (without any parameters). But this is not going to work when there are parameters such as href and id. I am trying to modify the above code to print the Text(between 2 anchor tags), URL(HREF) and id in the following manner

**Text: Google URL:https://www.google.lk/ id:21**

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Thanks for the help, it means a lot to me. I haven't accepted this as the answer because it is omitting anchor tags which do not have a id or a href. I am sorry if the question was not clear enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a little not clear, so if I understand correctly, you are able to extract the anchor tag (`<a>`) content easily but if the `<a` tag contains href and id, then you are thinking it won't work. Plus, as per your post title, you want to extract `href` and `id` attribute's values as well and they may or may not be there. And in fact any of them could be missing.

In this case, you can use this regex,

```
<(a)(?:\s+href=(['"])(?<href>[^'"]*)\2\s*)?(?:\s+id=(['"])(?<id>[^'"]*)\4\s*)?>(.+?)<\/\1>
```

**Explanation:**

- `<` --> start of tag
- `(a)` --> Expects the tag name to be `a' only and captures it in group 1 for matching it by back referencing at closing end
- `(?:\s+href=(['"])(?<href>[^'"]*)\2\s*)?` --> This part matches `href` attribute and captures its value in `href` named group which is optional
- `(?:id=(['"])(?<id>[^'"]*)\4\s*)?` --> This part matches `id` attribute and captures value in `id` named group which is optional too
- `>` end of `<a` tag
- `(.+?)` --> Captures `<a` tags inner text
- `<\/\1>` --> Matches ending tag for `<a` through back referencing through `\1`

This will still match group 1 reference which will be `a` according to above regex, as well as will capture `href` and `id` attribute's values as well, both being optional.

[Here is a demo](https://regex101.com/r/LoapsL/2)

Let me know if this is what you wanted. In case of any queries, do let me know.

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted. Thank you. I was stuck here for a few days. Thanks a lot. One more thing, can you suggest me a place to start learning regex expression formation. 
Thanks for the help, it means a lot to me
 
Kind Regards

Comment: @Shota: So happy to help you too :) And for learning regex, although there are many tutorials out there but I liked https://www.regular-expressions.info/ and love http://regex101.com for playing/debugging with regex. Checkout this page from Stackoverflow too https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info which gives you valuable info and awesome references

Comment: There is one more thing, above regex seems to neglect anchor tags which only have an id or href( eg- <a href="www.Google3.com">Problem4</a>
  <a id="id5">Problem4</a> ) .

Comment: @Shota: I have updated the regex and demo URL to fix the issue. Problem was, spaces constraint was little not relaxed and now it takes care. Let me know if you face any issues further.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. It is working. Sorry for the bit late reply as I was trying to add another modification to the code. I am trying to modify it to work even with the missing quotations in href of id. (eg- <a href=?view=admin&admin=1>Course Registration</a>) .Sorry if any inconvenience is caused due to my problems

Comment: @Shota: No problem dear. Let me know if you want me to make it match even if there are no doublequotes or singlequotes enclosing to the value of href or id

Comment: @Shota: Ok, here it is. Use this regex if you want `"` or `'` can be optionally present in the value of attributes. `<(a)(?:\s+href=(['"]?)(?<href>[^'"]*?)\2\s*)?(?:\s+id=(['"]?)(?<id>[^'"]*?)\4\s*)?>(.+?)<\/\1>` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LoapsL/3)

Comment: thank you very much for your support.you are a life saver

Answer (score 0):

***Edited to make id/href optional***

Find

`<a(?=\s|>)(?=(?:(?:[^>"']|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*?\shref\s*=\s*(?:(['"])([\S\s]*?)\1))?)(?=(?:(?:[^>"']|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*?\sid\s*=\s*(?:(['"])([\S\s]*?)\3))?)\s*(?:"[\S\s]*?"|'[\S\s]*?'|[^>]*?)+>(.*?)</a\s*>`

Replace

`Text: $5 URL:$2 id:$4`

https://regex101.com/r/SBgqqd/1

Expanded

```
                               # Begin Anchor tag
 < a
 (?= \s | > )
 (?=                           # Asserttion for optional:  href  (a pseudo atomic group)
      (?:
           (?: [^>"'] | " [^"]* " | ' [^']* ' )*?
           \s href \s* = \s* 
           (?:
                ( ['"] )                      # (1)
                ( [\S\s]*? )                  # (2)
                \1 
           )
      )?
 )
 (?=                           # Asserttion for optional:  id
      (?:
           (?: [^>"'] | " [^"]* " | ' [^']* ' )*?
           \s id \s* = \s*           
           (?:
                ( ['"] )                      # (3)
                ( [\S\s]*? )                  # (4)
                \3 
           )
      )?
 )
                               # Have the href and id, just match the rest of tag
 \s* 
 (?: " [\S\s]*? " | ' [\S\s]*? ' | [^>]*? )+

 >                             # End  tag

 ( .*? )                       # (5)
 </a \s* >
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, it means a lot to me

Comment: @Shota - I always give people a second chance. Edited for optional params. Take a close look at the target sample here https://regex101.com/r/SBgqqd/1.  If parsing tags correctly and getting specific attributes were that easy you get the answer you chose. I'll leave this post here for any connoisseurs that happen by in the future.